# Scaling variable in ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

Let's say we have an ODEs system of the type:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial \vec{y}(t)}{\partial t}=f(t,\vec{y}(t),\partial_{t}\vec{y}(t) ),
\end{eqnarray}
with $t\in[0,\infty)$. We want now to scale the independent variable $t$ so that $t=x/1-x$ for $x\in [0,1)$. Then, upon computing the RHS of this equation, we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial\vec{y}}{\partial x} = \left(\frac{d t}{d x}\right)\frac{\partial \vec{y}}{\partial t}.
\end{eqnarray}
How can we correctly account for such transformation in the ODE? What I am doing: I always evaluate $f(t,\vec{y}(t),\partial_{t}\vec{y}(t) )$ with each evaluation of the RHS; for example, suppose I want to calculate a single differential step with a Runge-Kutta of 4th order; then the RHS needs to be evaluated 5 times to get a solution point in the interval $[0,1)$. At the end of each of the 5 evaluations, since I want $\frac{\partial\vec{y}}{\partial x}$, I multiply the whole result by the prefactor $\left(\frac{d t}{dx}\right)$, is that correct? In other words, I am just multiplying the $k_{i}$ of the RK implementation by the corresponding factors given by $\left(\frac{d t}{d x}\right)$.

Explicitly, knowing the solution at $(t_{n},y_{n})$, the first RK coefficients become:
\begin{eqnarray}
k_{1} &=&f(t_{n},y_{n})\to k_{1}.\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)\bigg|_{x=x(t_{n})}\nonumber\\
k_{2} &=&f(t_{n}+h/2, y_{n}+hk_{1}/2)\to k_{2}.\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)\bigg|_{x=x(t_{n}+h/2)}\nonumber\\
&\vdots &
\end{eqnarray}
Is this the correct way to perform the scaling?

Comment: Which is the correct version of $f$, the first one with 3 arguments or the one in the RK method with 2 arguments? How do you solve the implicit equation $\dot y=f(t,y,\dot y)$?

Comment: It should be the second one, the RHS does not depend on the derivatives in my case, only on the state vector $y(t)$,

Comment: In general you can not go in finitely many RK4 steps to infinity or to the singularity after the reparametrization, and get useful results. What should be simple enough to implement is to increase $h=h_n$ after each step. However this might still lead to leaving the stability domain of the method. Otherwise use a far-field approximation to cover the solution after some sufficiently large cut-off, especially if the system approaches an asymptote.

Comment: This was one of my main problems on dealing with the initial, starting point of the ODEs, as a value very close to 1 seems to accumulate errors with each step after many evaluations. The increment of $h$ is done with the adaptive step for a Runge-Kutta-Cash-Karp.